# Keyboard and Trackpad are not working on Macbook Air Using Ubuntu TLS

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, macbook, macbook-air

first at all i want to say hello. I'm new in the world of Ubuntu and new in this forum.

Now to the problem.

I have to install Ubuntu on my MacBook Air 2020 for my university (i ordered a lenovo but it will arrive in more than a month)

Information about the Mac:

- It runs on an Intel i3 dual core
- Modell-identifier: "macbookair9,1"

Information about my Ubuntu installation:

- Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Ubuntu just works fine. But i am not able to use my keyboard or trackpad. Extern devices are working.

I installed ubuntu with a lan connection. (WIFI does not work also) And allowed the installation to download drivers.

I hope someone can help me. Itried a mass of tutorials out there but nothing works.

Regards
Marvin